# Gradle build with Ajc fails due to Temporary file creation

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

My [project](https://github.com/flamusdiu/ffxiv_db) has an interesting issue with Gradle. When running "gradle build" from inside Intellij 13 (windows or linux), I get the following error message:

```
10:05:48 PM: Executing external task 'build'...
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:compileAspect FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileAspect'.
> Error creating temporary file

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 7.434 secs
Access is denied
10:05:56 PM: External task execution finished 'build'.
```

From here, I ran a full debug located here: [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/sNgL5aXg)

Which shows it failing in the AjcTask.java file at the below line:

```
1993  tmpFile = File.createTempFile("argfile", "", userDir);
```

Might be related to [GRADLE-1400](http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1400) which is for and older version but unresolved. On linux, if I `cd` to the project directory, I can run "gradle build" without trouble after that first time, then I can run it from Intellij as well without an issue.

Maybe the environment vars getting nuke somehow?

Comment: Do You have a `write` access to the temporary dir where such files are created?

Comment: @Opal I should have write access but where is it trying to write to? If I run it from CLI once after I have Intellij open, then it works in the IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like [GRADLE-2532](http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2532).

`user.dir` property defaults to `C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.1\jre\jre\bin` in your case which causes `Access Denied` error.

In IDEA 13.1.2 and previous versions enabling [Use customizable gradle wrapper](http://img845.imageshack.us/img845/9346/s9kc.png) option should help. This will set `user.dir` to the project root directory.

In IDEA 13.1.3 and later versions there are different workarounds available, check [this comment](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-118062#comment=27-724769).

Comment: That's silly. I guess the same issue would happen on Linux as well. Umm ... any idea why it works after you run it first from CLI? Does it cache the `user.dir` somehow?

Comment: Don't know why it works from CLI. Could be that this step doesn't run at all as the required files are already built.

Comment: I think it might be related to GRADLE-2532 as well from reading the comments on that. Let me change to using the other gradle wrapper and I'll let you know.

Comment: Looks like using the customizable gradle wrapper option works. However, I am not sure why though. @CrazyCoder can you explain how this works?